# Find documents per category

Tags: elasticsearch

IM a newbie to elasticsearch world.
 I have done an aggregation and got the results. Now I need to see which documents are inside each category/buckets. How to do the same?

Comment: By "category/buckets", do you mean index? What is the aggregation you ran?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation as a sub-aggregation of your `terms` aggregation, like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "categories": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "category"
            },
            "aggs": {                        <--- add this sub-aggregation
                "top_category_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```